# Error executing HTTP.Post call from Microsite landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page, microsites

Here's my code below.  The error happens at the first HTTP.Post call.  The error message is simply:

```
ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException:  An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call.  See inner exception for details.
Source:  OMMCommon
```

This had previously worked for me before.  I double checked the syntax on the HTTP.Post call, everything seems fine.  Is there anything I'm just missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Paused_Automations_SMS_Notification','ReturnAll','1');
    if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
       var tokenURL = 'https://hhhhhhhhhh.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
       var payload = {
           "clientId": "hhhhhhhhh",
           "clientSecret": "hhhhhhhhhhh"
       };
       var contentType = 'application/json';
       var resultToken = HTTP.Post(tokenURL, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
       var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultToken["Response"][0]).accessToken;

       var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
       var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

       for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
           var smsurl = 'https://hhhhhhhhhh.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO';
            var smsPayload = {
                "mobileNumbers" : [
                dataRows[i].MobileNumber
            ],
                "shortCode" : "80565",
                "messageText" : "MIKETESTERLE" + " " + dataRows[i].AutomationName
            };
            var smsresult = HTTP.Post(smsurl, contentType, Stringify(smsPayload), headerNames, headerValues);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: V2 token generation JSON payload needs to be updated. Sufficiently answered here .https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271535/ssjs-oauth-2-support

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to use a v2 auth endpoint with v1 client credentials.

In your `tokenURL`, try replacing: `/v2/token` with:  `/v1/requestToken`