# SSJS code to fetch the json response returned in the browser after authentication in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to connect My Cloud page to Google Sheets.
In my Cloud Page I have embedded this code - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221FoNQeZv1TIuOCwobEshcplrTPBhk3RnsmjP3s9-MlQA%22%2C%22range%22%3A%221%22%7D.

After authentication, I am returned back to my origin URI(that is my cloud page) with a json response in the console.

My Question is, how to use SSJS to fetch this returned value ? I have attached the screenshot of the response.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have hard time fetching these values with SSJS, as the request you are executing is done in frontend Java Script (where SSJS is running in the backend). This means, that the response received is "too late for the party", as your SSJS has already finished executing, when the content of your Google Sheet is returned to the page.

I will advise you to look more into the backend integration, using [oAuth authentication](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing). There is a number of threads here on SFSE, describing the [use of oAuth in SFMC/SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271535/ssjs-oauth-2-support).

As I have never built integrations towards Google APIs, I can't give you any advice on the API specifics. I am actually not even sure, you can fully succeed with your integration (depending on the solution you are building), as the initial request to Google must provide user login and consent, even before you can fetch a token for authenticating subsequent API requests:

[image]

Given that you intend to use this SSJS in Automation Studio, this can prove to be a road blocker. I will at least do some more research on whether or not content can be retrieved without authorising a user.

A workaround could be to make the sheet public. This makes retrieving data much easier, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395001/is-there-a-restful-google-sheets-api-for-reading-rows-from-one-sheet), but can be a no-go, if your data is somewhat sensitive.